# Avoid Stretching UIImageView inside a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UIView in a UIViewController in Storyboard. There is a UIImageView inside it.

I want to increase the height of UIView programmatically:

```
CGRect frame = headerV.frame;
frame.size.height = 100;
headerV.frame = frame;
```

The problem is it also stretch the UIImageView. If I do not want to add the UIImage programmatically, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 - using resizing flags**

A) Disable autoresizesSubviews on `headerV.autoresizesSubviews = NO`.
or
B) Setup the correct autoresizingMask on your imageView. Do this:
`imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`,
if it should stick to the top (or smth. else - whatever setup you want)

**Option B - autolayout**

setup your autolayout correspondingly ,)

(PS: You can do all of this in interfaceBuilder or within the code.)

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your storyboard, click on the UIImageView, open the size inspector and be sure to disable stretching width and height (in autosizing). It should look like this :

[image]

Comment: Found this fixed it after a good hour of trying to figure it out.  THANKS!  That autosizing graphic is pretty stupidly hard to understand...

Answer (score 1):

Set `autoresizesSubviews` property of your UIView to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stretch the image then set it's `contentMode`

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```